# send data to and from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project where I need to get a class (with approximately 20 variables) from my controller to a view, and then I need to get the data back to my controller. I know I can use ViewBag variables, but that seems so tedious for that many variables, and I don't want to use a model because the data won't necessarily come from or go to a database. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: A view model doesn't have to have anything to do with a database.  It is simply a means of passing data back and forth between a controller and a view.  A view model combined with hidden fields on a view should be fine.

Comment: 20+ hidden fields on a single view? There isn't a way to pass the whole model back to the controller at once?

Comment: Yes - view model binding, where you defined the view model, and have your form post to a controller action that accepts the view model, and MVC will take care of mapping the fields to the view model.  Maybe you want to provide more context to your problem, and concrete details of why a view model is not workable.

Comment: If you want to avoid passing data back and forth in a model you could just have some simple ajax GET/POST requests from your view to the controller to send and receive data as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model. Models don't have to be connected to a database. They're very handy for usage in forms. Here's a very simplified example of what you can do:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
   // .... etc
}
```

Load form

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyForm()
{
   return View(new PersonViewModel());
}
```

Post form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyForm(PersonViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

View (bound to PersonViewModel)

```
@model PersonViewModel

<h1>Person Form</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: Can I assign javascript variables to model variables? (ex. I have a date input which is made up of three separate fields, could I assign `var myDate = "mm/dd/yyy"` to `model.date`?

Comment: Yes. You also have the option of creating 3 separate properties for the date in your view model, then error check + merge into one field on the server side after you submit your form.